# Blazor C# - Using CSS isloation with code file behind component

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I have problems with getting a css file places behind a razor component to work

I have 3 files:

- Index.razor
- Index.razor.cs
- Index.razor.css

but the css in the .css file is not used in the Index.razor page

Do I need to switch anything one or how do i make it work?

Indexfile content:

```
@page "/"

@namespace TestCSSIsolation.Pages

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<input value="@value" />
<button @onclick="@OnClick_Button">Click</button>
```

.cs file content:

```
namespace TestCSSIsolation.Pages;

public partial class Index
{
    private string value = string.Empty;
    private void OnClick_Button()
    {
        if (value.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            value = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            value = "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

.css file content:

```
body {
    border: solid 10px red;
}

button {
    background-color: pink;
}

input {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Unfortunately I not allowed to post pictures here, but the result when I run the application is that the styling in the css file is not used on the component.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me!
[image: output]
I was having trouble adding razor files to VS.
Suggestion: Delete the file and add a new one.
[image: File structure]

Comment: I tried adding a new razor component and added a css file to it also but still no luck.

Comment: Are there any setting that need to be done to switch this feature on/off, or something else that need to be added to the project to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `_Host.cshtml` has your CSS file included. To get scoped CSS working there should be a line like this:

```
<link href="[YOUR#_PROJECT_NAME].styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another question that led me to a solution.

If I add this to my razor component then it works:

```
<head>
    <link href="TestCSSIsolation.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

where "TestCSSIsolation" is my project name.